# The target table TAD of the UPDATE is not updatable

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to run this query but I got this error message:

```
UPDATE (SELECT * FROM Tb_Accounting_Documents
        WHERE date_at BETWEEN Start_Date AND DATE_ADD(End_Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as TAD
SET TAD.final_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    TAD.final_user_id = @Auth_User;
```

> The target table TAD of the UPDATE is not updatable

Comment: 'The target table TAD of the UPDATE is not updatable' - true, a select produces a virtual table and is not a valid table_reference.A valid table_reference is a table name.

Answer (score 1):

supply your columns to update.

```
UPDATE (SELECT final_at, final_user_id  FROM Tb_Accounting_Documents
        WHERE date_at BETWEEN Start_Date AND DATE_ADD(End_Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) TAD
SET TAD.final_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    TAD.final_user_id = @Auth_User;
```

or use this basic update DML

```
UPDATE Tb_Accounting_Documents
SET final_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        final_user_id = @Auth_User
WHERE date_at BETWEEN Start_Date AND DATE_ADD(End_Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UPDATE Tb_Accounting_Documents
SET final_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    final_user_id = @Auth_User
WHERE date_at BETWEEN Start_Date AND DATE_ADD(End_Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
UPDATE Tb_Accounting_Documents ts
inner join (SELECT * FROM Tb_Accounting_Documents
WHERE date_at BETWEEN Start_Date AND DATE_ADD(End_Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY))TAD 
on join condition 
SET  ts.final_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
ts.final_user_id = @Auth_User;
```